# set get data attributes

Tags: jquery

This gets the attribute

```
console.log(doc.find('[data-monitor="total_gross"]').data('amount'));
```

This should set the attribute, but doesn't

```
doc.find('[data-monitor="total_gross"]').data('amount', total_gross);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `.attr()` instead

Comment: What is `doc`? And keep in mind, setting a `data` will not be shown in you html, its jQuery internal. Otherwise use `attr('data-amount', total_gross)` instead of `data`.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/kj95rfkh/. Please add some more details of the exact issue. Note that `data()` does not change anything in the DOM, it just sets the value in jQuery's internal data object cache. So long as you use `data()` as a getter/setter then there is no issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update in the markup you need to use **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method

```
doc.find('[data-monitor="total_gross"]').attr('data-amount', total_gross);
```

Refer : [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Comment: il mark sa dup on the link you gave ok?

Comment: He does not say, that he want to have it in the markup. His original post is not even wrong. So saying `you need to use` is not correct. He is not *need* to. He can ...

Comment: Important to point our that `.data()` -will- update the data attribute, and will be accessible later, just not the actual visible attribute on the DOM element

Comment: @eisbehr :  for updating in markup he __need__ to...

Comment: @PranavCBalan Yes. But who was asking for updating the markup?

Comment: @eisbehr :  if he is saying `.data('amount', total_gross);` is not working.... from that we can predict that... let's wait for the response from asker :)